# Elegant way to adjust this angle (which has another object which must stay parallel to it)

Tags: geometry

[image: wedge that needs a different angle]

Hi,
So I decided i want a steeper angle on this hollow wedge.
I want to move the green vertices to where the red marks are.

but the object marked purple is embedded in the face, and if I just move the green vertices, it will deform and look awful and wreck my nice flat face.

purple object also protrudes through the face to the other side.

Anyway, how would -you- sort this out?

[image]

heres a wireframe view, i've attempted to rotate the lot, but the bottom vertices need to be extended to EXACLY in the right place, but i dunno how to ensure that precision

Comment: I'd select the entire face, the little protrusion, and wherever else you need to maintain an angle. Then move the entirety of it to the position you want.

Comment: i may have misssed something..

so I selected the vertice at the top of the angle, mesh>snap>cursor to selected. [object mode]>object>set origin>origin to 3d cursor. [edit mode] select all teh vertices of the face as Nascent Space suggests, rotate until the bottom edge is kinda pointing the right direction. but now i need to extend the vertices on the bottom edge to exactly where they would have hit.. still stuck -- question updated--

Comment: one possibility would be to separate the object on the face, then adapt your face with vertex-movements and after you have done it, snap the separated object back to the face and join.

Comment: Hi chris, my problem with this was, that by extending the bottom vertices, i change the angle of the face, leaving the separated object at a different angle. so then i'm kinda lining it all up by eye and .. it just bothers me

Comment: So then wouldn't moving all of it maintain that angle?

Comment: Hi Nascent, yeh 'just' moving it would be pointless because it would maintain the angle. which i why i had to rotate it, which causes problems because the face now needs to be longer to meet the bottom panel. the 'elegance' i'm looking for, is a way to keep thje entire face and object at its new angle AND have the lower vertices maintain their x (or y) axis despite the change in face length

Answer (score 0):

see my response to Nascent space above,
the missing link was to then change 'transform orientation' to normal, which allows me to scale the face along its face.

BUT not as elegant as hoped, because i ended up having to carefully line up the bottom vertices with the face of that bottom plate. error there doesn't bother me as much, but its not perfect, so still interested in ideas